# Django ORM to Spring Hibernate mapping

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

What would be the closest commands (if there are commands) for a userRepository that contains a User entity in spring/hibernate?

1. Get an object by PK/ID: `User.objects.get(id=2)`
2. Get an object by field(s): `User.objects.get(name="david", age=20)`
3. Get objects by field(s): `User.objects.filter(name="david")`
4. Delete an object by field(s): `User.objects.filter(name="david").delete)`
5. Update an object by field(s): `User.objects.filter(name="david").update(name="dave")`

How would I do the above in Java/Spring off of my UserRepository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `UserRepository` like this:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    User findOneByNameAndAge(String name, int age); // Answer point 2

    List<User> findByName(String name); // Answer point 3

    @Modifying
    @Query("delete from User u where u.name = ?1")
    int deleteByName(String name); // Answer point 4

    @Modifying
    @Query("update User u set u.name = ?1 where u.name = ?2")
    int updateByName(String newName, String oldName); // Answer point 5
}
```

Note that for point 1 of your questions, `JpaRepository` already provide this method for you:

`userRepository.findOne(2);`

Here's how you use it:

```
// Provide necessary annotations..
public class UserRepositoryIntTest {

    @Autowired UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    public void testThemAll() {
        this.userRepository.findOne(2); // 1
        this.userRepository.findOneByNameAndAge("david", 20); // 2
        this.userRepository.findByName("david"); // 3
        this.userRepository.deleteByName("david"); // 4
        this.userRepository.updateByName("dave", "david"); // 5
    }

}
```

HTH

Comment: so you have to explicitly specify which fields you want to query? You can't just "automagically" do a delete or update by any of those field names, correct?

Comment: > You can't just "automagically" do a delete or update by any of those field names, correct?

Correct. This is by fact because Java is statically typed language, while python is dynamic typed one.